The master view must be shown when we choose
when we select the master view it's not display once the menu item closed.
        <MenuItem
          onClick={(event) => this.handleMasterView(event, masterView)}
          component="a"
          href="/cgi-bin/admin2.cgi?clear_session_dealer_eid=1"
          selected={!currentDealer.name}
        >
          <Typography>Master View</Typography>
        </MenuItem>


How we can identify the issue with this piece of code ?
